# Linq where doesn't remove null from type

Tags: c#, linq, nullable-reference-types

I'm confused why this doesn't work and what an alternative might be.  I suppose I could create a non-null version of `MaybeNull` but this issue keeps recurring I'd have to make a lot of duplicate functions.  The 'MaybeNull' extension is used in other places where the null is relevant, and like I say, there's a bunch of them with a similar setup.

```
#nullable enable
using System;   
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MyClass
{
    private List<string> ParseList(List<string> source)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        //problem is this line
        result.AddRange(source.Select(x => x.MaybeNull()).Where(x => x != null));
        return result;
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string? MaybeNull(this string? input)
    {
        if (input == null) return null;
        return input + "modified";
    }
}
#nullable disable
```

So despite the where clause it's trying to add `string?` items to the `List<string>` result which obviously won't work.  I can make it work if I do a foreach

```
private List<string> ParseList2(List<string> source)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
        
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var modifiedItem = item.MaybeNull();
        if (modifiedItem != null) result.Add(modifiedItem);
    }
            
    return result;
}
```

Something like this looks like it would work for a list of `Int` but not for string or other more complex types.

```
result.AddRange(source.Select(x => x.MaybeNull())
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Select(x => x.Value));
```

Is there a way to achieve a similar result using a nice linq one liner?

EDIT:  In response to comments, the actual code it isn't even a string (so string.IsNullOrEmpty isn't an option), it's a complex Class that gets modified in an extension which is designed to handle nulls.  There are lots of extensions like this  I'm now implementing nullable reference types on an established code base.

EDIT2:  Part of the reason that this is bugging me is that ReSharper says "hey this foreach can be a linq statement! =D " and then it converts it into the invalid linq seen above -_-

Comment: Why not just do .Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(s=>s); or .Select(s=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));

Comment: @AliK you have seen the implementation of the method and not just assumed its functionality by its name?

Comment: @Ralf from my understanding OP is trying to only add non-null values to a list.

Comment: @AliK Look again. The implementation is in the question.

Comment: I have found in the source for example the string may not actually be NULL like for example if there is an empty space, hence the suggestion.

Comment: Is it adding null items to the list, or the type string? with populated items?

Comment: @ itsdaniel0 the result of the source.Select... is List<string?> so I'm getting compiler warnings about adding items from List<string?> to List<string>.  Though as I've said the actual code it's not a string it's a Class.

Comment: This is to do with the way .Where() behaves
.Where(x => x != null) will always return a type of T?

Comment: @itsdaniel0 yea basically.  Wondering if there's a way I can guarantee a non-null type using linq or something more concise than a foreach with a temporary variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the compiler still sees the result from .Where() as a nullable T?

If you want to resolve this via LINQ, I'd recommend a custom extension method that tells the compiler your items aren't null.
You'll need to use alternative LINQ syntax

```
var nullable = new List<string?>
{
    "Hello",
    null,
    "World"
};

var notNull = nullable.WhereNotNull();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', notNull));

internal static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> enumerable)
        where T : class
    {
        return from e in enumerable
               where e is not null
               select e;
    }
}

// Outputs: Hello,World
```

Comment: Most excellent.  Though I'll note, .NET Fiddle was happy with your code, once I threw it into VS it complained about "[NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(enumerable))] ", cannot resolve symbol enumerable and it suggested the nullability attribute has no effect and can be safely removed.  It seems to work just fine cutting that bit out of the extension.

Comment: Name of for parameter names is a newer feature, so probably why. Good to know the attribute wasn't needed at all though. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options here. Null-forgiving operator:

```cs
List<string> result = source
    .Select(x => x.MaybeNull())
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .ToList()!; // though it can suppress too much
```

or

```cs
var result = source
    .Select(x => x.MaybeNull())
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Select(x => x!)
    .ToList();
```

or just simple `Enumerable.Cast`:

```cs
result.AddRange(source.Select(x => x.MaybeNull()).Where(x => x != null).Cast<string>());
```

Or just use `OfType` trick:

```cs
var result = source
    .Select(x => x.MaybeNull())
    .OfType<string>()
    .ToList();
```