# Is there something similar to NotNullIfNotNullAttribute for IEnumerable return values?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-7.0, nullable-reference-types

*(This is a question about [C# nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and generics.)*

I know that [I can use `NotNullIfNotNullAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) to specify that the return value of my method may be null if, and only if, an input is null:

```
[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(defaultValue))]
public T? GetValueOrDefault<T>(T? defaultValue)
{ 
    return GetValueFromSomewhere<T>() ?? defaultValue;
}
```

Is there something similar for methods returning `IEnumerable<T>`? I'd like to tell the compiler that all **elements** of the returned IEnumerable are non-null **if** the input parameter is non-null.

```
[return: ???]
public IEnumerable<T?> GetValuesOrDefault<T>(T? defaultValue)
{
    return GetValuesFromSomewhere<T>().Select(x => x ?? defaultValue);
}
```

---

Here's a MCVE ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/myhcNi)) to play around with:

```
#nullable enable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string? s1 = GetValueOrDefault<string>(null);
        string s2 = GetValueOrDefault<string>("");   // works, C# realizes that the return value can't be null
        
        IEnumerable<string?> e1 = GetValuesOrDefault<string>(null);
        IEnumerable<string> e2 = GetValuesOrDefault<string>("");   // I want to get rid of the warning here
    }
    
    [return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(defaultValue))]
    public static T? GetValueOrDefault<T>(T? defaultValue)
    { 
        return GetValueFromSomewhere<T>() ?? defaultValue;
    }
    
    public static IEnumerable<T?> GetValuesOrDefault<T>(T? defaultValue)
    {
        return GetValuesFromSomewhere<T>().Select(x => x ?? defaultValue);
    }
    
    // Dummy placeholders for my MCVE. My real methods read values from my DB repository.
    private static T? GetValueFromSomewhere<T>() => default(T);
    private static IEnumerable<T?> GetValuesFromSomewhere<T>() => new T?[] { default(T) };
}
```

Comment: Does this help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75475662/linq-where-doesnt-remove-null-from-type/75476487#75476487

Comment: @itsdaniel0 I would argue that question is not about how to filter out nulls. Actually nulls in the result are pretty much appropriate in some cases - see the `IEnumerable<string?> e1 = GetValuesOrDefault<string>(null);` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is already possible.

In this case, both the input and output whose nullability we want to modify are of type `T`, a type parameter on the enclosing method. We don't need `[NotNullIfNotNull]` here — we can just use method type argument inference to achieve what we want. [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEAMACdBGAFgG4BYAKC1zwDoAZWAR1LPIHpXsB7Aa3PwGYAPPkwA+bBGwBebAHEApgBcAahAA2AV3kBnAPIAnACLyAZhA1rFAChjyA7gG0AutgDe2AEQQPcbDAtq2AC+vgim5paqmvIgnsAeAJTMAsJ4YtjA0nJKUVp6RuEW1raOLu5ePnEewaGFkepasR7xSeRsHHYQ+jCwAOaxAHIBEMBQalCKAJ5cJtj6pvLzMADG8thTAA462LDYAG4Na5yzm2sA5CkiAPyiZ9gInDowZ4rYkIrLABbrXb1K65MttgLnghCJbtQ+KDUulllkFCpDvljGYijZ7M43J5vL5/GpAiF7nVEdFYni1K0WFSUgAVcQI3I6AwoiKKQR0qy0m77JEAMX0nDAAGVBfZPot5L4aUTUfVoglyK5yNgVbgAOw86LafmCkVgMUS6hC+RqeTLawAD2k4itVyuMtZjMpQSAA==).

```cs
// ok
IEnumerable<string> a = GetValuesOrDefault(new[] { "a", null }, defaultValue: "b");
IEnumerable<string> b = GetValuesOrDefault(new[] { "a", "b" }, defaultValue: "b");

// warning: Nullability of reference types in value of type 'IEnumerable<string?>' doesn't match target type 'IEnumerable<string>'.
IEnumerable<string> c = GetValuesOrDefault(new[] { "a", null }, defaultValue: null);


IEnumerable<T> GetValuesOrDefault<T>(IEnumerable<T?> valuesFromSomewhere, T defaultValue)
{
    return valuesFromSomewhere.Select(x => x ?? defaultValue);
}
```

This gives us the point of control we want here: If the `defaultValue` going in is non-nullable, the result IEnumerable has a non-nullable type argument. If the `defaultValue` going in may be null, the result IEnumerable has a nullable type argument.

Answer (score 1):

No, sadly but currently there is no such thing (at least via attributes). There same issue can be observed with tasks, which is  discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2793) (or [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/45228)), but based on comments it seems that at the moment only task-specific and `async`-`await` case are taken into consideration (see also [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/6888) discussion).